# Updating ASP.NET project to HTML5

Tags: asp.net, html

I have an ASP.NET 2.0 application.  I would like to start enhancing it with HTML5 specific tags/features.
Does it mean that the first step is to change the line:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" >
```

at the top of each .ASPX file with

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

And then any HTML5 specific tag I use will be ok?

Comment: Editing tip (can't apply it myself right now): Put backquotes around the HTML you want to embed in the question.

Answer (score 1):

ASP.NET is mostly a server-side technology which won't have *a lot* to do with HTML5.  You can certainly use HTML5 elements in your application, but, you will also be limited to using certain elements that are generated by the ASP.NET WebForms framework.

As an example, you could use the HTML5 DOCTYPE, `<!DOCTYPE html>`, or you could use the `article` element or `data` attributes.  None of this really has much of an impact on the ASP.NET server-side technology.

Comment: I understand. Unfortunately the code that I tried to show in my post is all gone. I need to learn to format the code correctly.
Thank you

Comment: @Hidalgo - If you have a specific question about a snippet of code feel free to make the edit and I can take a look.

Comment: Actually you showed in your reply some of the code that I wanted to show in my initial message.  But I don't know how to format the code to make it look.  But basically you answered my question.  I need to change at the top of the .ASPX pages the DOCTYPE syntax with the HTML5 type (as you shown)

Comment: @Hidalgo - You can certainly do that.  You're essentially telling the browser to render your document in standards mode.  Flipping the DOCTYPE won't magically introduce any new HTML5 elements however.  It *might* change how your site is rendered across different browsers though.

Comment: @EkOnomik - Thank you for your help.  I will try by introducing a few HTML5-specific tags, outside of the ASP.NET controls to see how they are rendered.